# getdata and curve fitting from a graph in maple

Tags: graphing-functions, maple

I plot a parametric curve  from the functions
$$f(r):=-(1/2)*(r^3-1)/r^2,$$
$$ g(r):=-(1/6)*(-r^3-9)/r^2$$
$$plot([   f(r),g(r) , r=0.1..1]);$$
in maple.
I am looking for the best curve fitting function of the $f$-$g$ graph.
How can I accomplish it in maple?
I hope to have a function like $f= a*g^2 + b*g + c $ after the curve fitting.

Answer (score 1):

This answer concerns only the fitting part of the question, what ever the software to draw it.

Parametric equation : $\quad\begin{cases}
x=g(r)=\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\\
y=f(r)=\frac{1-r^3}{2\:r^2} \end{cases}$

Fitting with an equation on the form :
$$f(g)\simeq F(g)=a\:g^2+b\:g+c$$
with the mean square deviation method.

Considering the local square deviation $\quad\epsilon(r)^2=(F(g)-f(g))^2$
$$\epsilon(r)^2=\left( a\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)+c-\frac{1-r^3}{2\:r^2} \right)^2$$
On the specified range $0.1\leq r\leq 1$ , the cumulative square deviation is :
$$\int_{0.1}^{1}\epsilon(r)^2 dr=\int_{0.1}^{1} \left( a\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)+c-\frac{1-r^3}{2\:r^2} \right)^2 dr$$
The minimum of deviation is achieved when the derivatives with respect to $a$ , $b$ and $c$ are nul :

$$\begin{cases}
\int_{0.1}^{1} \left( a\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)+c-\frac{1-r^3}{2\:r^2}\right) \left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)^2 dr=0 \\
\int_{0.1}^{1} \left( a\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)+c-\frac{1-r^3}{2\:r^2}\right) \left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right) dr=0 \\
\int_{0.1}^{1} \left( a\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)^2 + b\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)+c-\frac{1-r^3}{2\:r^2}\right) dr=0
\end{cases}$$
We have to solve this linear system for $a$ , $b$  and $c$.

[image]

The result is : $\quad \begin{cases}
a\simeq -0.000 073 239 09 \\
b\simeq 0.344 918 \\
c\simeq -0.419 327
\end{cases}$

The graphical representation shows that the deviation is larger when $r$ is close to $1$ (i.e.  for small $f$ and $g$).

The parametric curve is drawn in black. The fitted curve $f(g)=ag^2+bg+c$ is drawn in red.

[image]

All above is valid on the specified range. The full drawing of the parametric curve is :

[image]

IN ADDITION, CASE $a=0$ : FITTIG OF THE FUNCTION $f(g)\simeq F(g)=b\,g+c$

The method is the same as above, but simpler. No need to repeat the theory.
$$\begin{cases}
\int_{0.1}^{1} \left( b\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)+c-\frac{1-r^3}{2\:r^2}\right) \left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right) dr=0 \\
\int_{0.1}^{1} \left( b\left(\frac{9+r^3}{6\:r^2}\right)+c-\frac{1-r^3}{2\:r^2}\right) dr=0
\end{cases}$$
We have to solve this linear system for $b$  and $c$.

[image]

The result is : $\quad \begin{cases}
b\simeq 0.337 368 \\
c\simeq -0.366 444
\end{cases}$

The graphical representation below shows that the deviation is larger than above. This is not surprising since only two parameters $b,c$ are optimized instead of three $a,b,c$ before.

[image]

Comment: Ok. But is there a way to make this a command or program in maple.
 Now I try $f= ag + b$ type solution or $f= a exp(g) + b$ type solution because negative $a$ is not proper for me.

Comment: I suppose that it is possible to write a procedure to compute the integrals and the matrixes as it is shown in my answer. For the case $f=ag+b$, see the addition to my first answer. The case $f=a \exp(g)+b$ is obviously not convenient. The case $f=a\exp(c\,g)+b$ could eventually be convenient. But the fitting process is more complicated : One need non-linear regression software, or alternatively the direct method shown pp.15-18 in the paper https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales